# Mach (MACOSX): task_suspend() does not suspend and task_resume() has unexpected behavior

Tags: c, macos, mach, microkernel

**Problem**
I am using the mach interface to suspend tasks and resume them. The code I provided does exactly that: `sudo ./code -r <PID>` to resume and `sudo ./code -s <PID>` to suspend. This C program compiles and runs, both functions return KERN_SUCCESS, but they have the following problems:

1. `task_suspend` : it does not suspend the task, simple as that.
2. `task_resume` : *I had to use kill -SIGSTOP  to test it on a stopped task as `task_suspend` does not work*. It does resume the task, **but** for some reason, I cannot send SIGSTOP again. If I want to send a STOP signal again I need to perform SIGCONT (even if the task is already running).

**Setup**

- C programming language
- Mach interface
- MacOSX
- Mac with Apple Silicon processor

**Documentation**

1. In the [MIT mach interface documentation](https://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/task_suspend.html) it says `task_suspend` increments the suspend_count. Well, it does not. I checked by printing the suspend_count obtainable by `task_info()`, `task_threads()` and `thread_info()` (task suspend count and each thread's suspend count).
2. I checked the [Apple XNU code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.71.2/osfmk/kern/task.c.auto.html) and, although the implementation is different from the one in MIT, it should still work. There you can also find `task_suspend2()`, which I did not even know existed, and the `task_suspend_internal()`.

---

**Code**

```
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/mach_error.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OPTION_STOP   1
#define OPTION_RESUME 2

void check_and_usage(int argc, char **argv)
{
        if (argc == 2 && !strcmp(argv[1], "help")) {
                fprintf(stdout, "\nmtask [-OPTION] [PIDs ..]\n\n[OPTIONS]\n     -r : RESUME a task.\n   -s : STOP a task.\n\n");
                exit(0);
        }
        if (argc < 3) {
                fprintf(stderr, "\nNot enough arguments provided!\nmtask [-OPTION] [PIDs ..]\n\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        if (strcmp(argv[1], "-s") && strcmp(argv[1], "-r")) {
                fprintf(stderr, "\nInvalid option!\n\n[OPTIONS]\n       -r : RESUME a task.\n   -s : STOP a task.\n\n");
                exit(1);
        }
}

void res_check(kern_return_t kern_res, char * msg)
{
        if (kern_res != KERN_SUCCESS) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s : %s\n", msg, mach_error_string(kern_res));
                exit(1);
        }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        check_and_usage(argc, argv);
        int type = 0;
        if (!strcmp(argv[1], "-s")) type = OPTION_STOP;
        else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "-r")) type = OPTION_RESUME;

        kern_return_t kern_res;

        for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
                mach_port_t task;
                int task_pid = atoi(argv[i]);

                kern_res = task_for_pid(mach_task_self(), task_pid, &task);
                res_check(kern_res, "Error fetching task from pid");

                switch (type) {
                        case OPTION_STOP:
                                kern_res = task_suspend(task);
                                break;
                        case OPTION_RESUME:
                                kern_res = task_resume(task);
                                break;
                }

                res_check(kern_res, "Error changing task state");
                mach_port_deallocate(mach_task_self(), task);
        }
}
```

---

**Additional things I tried**
I tried for a program to do `task_suspend(mach_task_self())` (suspend itself) and then resume it from another terminal. The program that supposedly suspends itself does stop, but I am not sure exactly why as `task_suspend()` should not work... Moreover, running `task_resume` for that program returns: `Error changing task state : (os/kern) failure`.

**I know there are alternatives to stop a task, but I am trying to learn and understand the mach interface. This behavior is unexpected and / or undocumented (or quite hidden!). Any information or link is appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

Both calls are working, but the suspension is pointless if the program is going to terminate, as upon its ending the suspended task will be automatically resumed. To make a similar program to what is described in the question alternatives must be found.

### Description

Looking in detail at the [latest implementation](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-7195.81.3/osfmk/kern/task.c.auto.html) of `task_suspend()` and `task_resume()` (xnu-7195.81.3) I understood what is going on. I will keep the question and answer in case someone runs into the same problems. Having said that, let's see why these problems are occurring:

1. `task_suspend()`

Looking at the [task.c](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-7195.81.3/osfmk/kern/task.c.auto.html) file from the Apple Developer repository and its implementation we can see that, after suspending the task, the process claims a send right on the task resume port. Notably, this is stored in the calling process IPC state (more info on IPC [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/Mach/Mach.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000905-CH209-CEGJEIAG)). Finally, the last step before returning is described in a comment within the C file

> Any IPC operations that deallocate the send right will auto-release the suspension.

Hence, the program which I provided, which only performs `task_suspend()` and finishes, resumes the suspended task upon its completion, as it is freeing the IPC space (which triggers resuming the task). **In other words, the call is working, but the suspended task is resumed once the calling process ends.**

2. `task_resume()`

The situation I described with the signals is quite peculiar. It is possible to deduce what part of the code got executed (knowing it returns KERN_SUCCESS and runs again the task) within the function implementation, but I am not sure why this happens. Somehow, the release function gets called thanks to this:

```
if (--task->user_stop_count == 0) {
            release = TRUE;
}
```

But how is the user_stop_count equal to 1 when no one suspended it? That is a question for next time.

What we can take from this is that Apple should probably make more documentation and more accessible (*personal opinion*).